# Angular file upload custom http post files

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

I am using nervgh/angular-file-upload to upload files. As I know, this angular-file-upload has their own upload functions.

Currently I need only the files inside the `uploader`, and then I will use my custom http post

```
$scope.UploadUserFiles = function () {
    $scope.UserFileRequest = {"File": uploader, "User": myUser}
    $http.post(host + "/api/user", $scope.UserFileRequest).then(function (response) { });
}
```

Currently I am having the trouble of getting those files from the `uploader` since I have no idea about the properties and structure. But for `User` is my own class at the web api, so I have no problem to get any info that I want.

The main problem is I have no idea how to catch/initialize the `uploader` it into a variable after post to my web api.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/user")]
public UserFileResponse GetUserFile(UserFileRequest userFileRequest)
{
  //What should I do to get the Files from the request and save into the server?
}
```

My `UserFileRequest` contain the info of `myUser`, but I do not know what to do with the `uploader` since I do not have a class to hold it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in your question, you are having trouble getting the files in the queue into your own file upload function.

The functions within the FileUploader class have callbacks that you can use, but another way to easily expose the file queue would be to create your own callback once the 'upload' button is clicked.

```js
someFxn(item) {
  console.log(item);
        
  _someUploadFxn(item)
}
```

```html
<md-button class="md-blue" ng-click="$ctrl.someFxn(item)" ng-disabled="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">
Upload
</md-button>
```

This will allow you to view the file that has been queued up and from there you can pass it or whatever properties you need off that file object into your own uploader function.

The same goes for if you are wanting to upload a bunch of files at once.